# How to validate a view or layout in robotium

Tags: android, robotium

I have showing different view in my android application how to validate weather the view or the whole layout is present  or not by using robotium in android.

Answer (score 2):

you can check this using `assertEquals`. There you can compare as
:

```
asserEquals("Desired View is not visible", yourView.getVisiblity(),View.VISIBLE);
```

Here, `View yourView = findViewById(R.id.yourViewId);`

Comment: Keep in mind, that view which have visibility equal VISIBLE may be not visible at all. For instance it may be covered by another view.

Comment: if this doesn't work you can try `assertTrue("view is not visible", yourView.isShown());`

Comment: ok this for a view how to check a layout like linear or relative layout if it doesn't have id .

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me - 
 `assertTrue("btnUseEmailToLogin View is not visible", (solo.getView("idName") ).isShown() == true);` 
Where idName - is the id of desired view to check